# Signing photography prints with personal name or business name

Tags: prints, selling

I have been reading a lot about how and where to sign photography prints, whether one should, and searching for examples of signed canvas wrapped and metal prints. Should I sign/digitally sign my personal name or "sign" the name of my photography business? And are the drawbacks for both options?

Comment: In what context? Limited edition fine art prints? Team pictures of the local little league teams? Etc?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Nature and landscape photography to be sold online and at a large continuous market.

Comment: Do you sign it for authentification purposes or to advertise yourself ?

Answer (score 1):

The first idea that comes to my mind...

The sign or tag is the first thing that the customer will see. If you sign the image by your name you are advertizing your personal services; if you sign the image by company label you are advertizing the company.

If you are the company, there is no legal issue there. Some people like their name and use it as a brand, some people doesnt and "hide" behind label or pseudonym.

If you are an employee paid for taking photos, it is completely different story, though. If you took the pictures for the company you must sign them with their label. It is possible to sign with both company label (the holder of the rights) and your name (the actual photographer). The only case you are entitled to sign the photos by your name only is the case when you took and edited the pictures during your leisure time.

Comment: Last paragraph would depend on the contract and applicable laws. In France for example you would be entitled by law to have your name appear ("droit de paternité") regardless of who owns copyright.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I registered a photography business so that both my husband and I could create within it.